# TextWrangler, How to hide page guide automatically?

Tags: textwrangler

I know there's an option item to show/hide page guide in TextWrangler, but I just wonder, if there's an operation to hide page guide automatically ever time I run TextWrangler application? AUTOMATICALLY!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try "Preferences"->"Appearance" and uncheck "Page guide" in the section "Editing window".